# changing anaconda folder path

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I recently have installed anaconda in my Ubuntu machine.By mistake,i shifted the anaconda folder from my home directory to inside another folder.Now when i tried to use anaconda command in the terminal it showed the error-'command not found'. Again i shifted my anaconda folder to it's by default home directory now it's working fine.Can anyone explain this all?

Is it related to some path dependency or something.Meanwhile, if i want to use anaconda while at the same time keeping it inside other folder what changes should i make and where?

Thanks a lot for your time and help!!!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your anaconda system PATH is created as per your home directory.

You can open your bashrc file and change the anaconda path to your desired anaconda installation location

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

check for line

```
export PATH=/home/{username}/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Replace /home/{username}/anaconda3/bin with your anaconda installation directory bin

Hope this helps :)